# Google Sign-In callback attribute not recognizing TypeScript function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to add a Google Sign-In button to my Angular web page's login component. The issue I'm facing is that the **`data-callback`** attribute of the Google Sign-In div **doesn't seem to recognize** the TypeScript function I've defined in my component. Here's a simplified version of my code:

In **`login.component.html`**:

```html
<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="your_client_id" data-callback="onSignInGoogle" class="mt-3"></div>
```

In **`login.component.ts`**:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  // ... other code ...

  onSignInGoogle(googleUser): void {
    console.log("onSignInGoogle has been called");
    // Additional logic for Google sign-in
  }
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that the Google Sign-In button's callback attribute **seems to be unable to recognize** the **`onSignInGoogle`** function declared in my TypeScript component. When inspecting the browser console, I get the error:

```cs
[GSI_LOGGER]: The value of 'callback' is not a function. Configuration ignored.
```

However, if I attach the function to an **`onclick`** listener, it works as expected. How can I **make the data-callback attribute recognize and call** my TypeScript function? Is there something I'm missing in terms of scope or initialization?

I've also tried modifying the callback using the **`Renderer2`** to directly set the attribute value, but that approach didn't seem to work either. I'd greatly appreciate any insights or guidance on how to **properly set up the Google Sign-In button callback** with a TypeScript function in an Angular component.

Comment: I'm no expert on google-signin, but ->`data-callback="onSignInGoogle"` I would expect this to be a global function, but you have it as a method on LoginComponent class.

Comment: @Keith, I've actually attempted declaring the function as a global one (inside the login.component.html) as you suggested, but unfortunately, it didn't yield any positive results. Intriguingly, I noticed that using the same `onSignInGoogle` method within an `onclick` attribute does work perfectly. Your insights on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you try to declare it as a global, note placing outside the class won't make it a global outside the module your using.   Could you try -> `window.onSignInGoogle = () => console.log("test")`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I did try declaring the function globally as you mentioned, but it didn't work as expected. What did the trick was using a combo of NgZone and putting the function on the global scope. It's working now. Your insights were a big help!

Comment: Ah, nice one.  I don't use angular, so I assume this is something specific to that.  Glad you have it all sorted now.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a callback function then it looks for function but you are passing a angular component function which will not work.

You can use my code to get it work.
In your component ts

```js
scriptLoaded = false;
ngOnInit() {
    // load the script when you actually need it
    const element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    element.onload = () => {
      // you can use scriptLoaded in html to show your div
      this.scriptLoaded = true;
      google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: "your-client-id",
        callback: (result) => {
          // you can write your code here
        },
      });
     
      // even you can render a gsi button from here also
      google.accounts.id.renderButton("your-element", {
          type: "standard",
          size: "large",
          logo_alignment: "left",
          shape: "rectangular",
          text: "continue_with",
          theme: "outline",
        }
        
    };
    element.async = true;
    element.defer = true;

    document.head.appendChild(element);
}
```

I hope it will help.